# How to change props when hovering over an element

Tags: angular, cesiumjs

I have this element where I want to access props and change the image or scale on hover using CSS, can anyone please guide me on how to do that and thank you.

```
<ac-billboard-desc 
class="pins" 
props="{ 
    position: internship.position,
    image : 'assets/logo7.png',
    scale: 0.25,
                }">
</ac-billboard-desc>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, in Cesium, those pins are rendered with WebGL.  They're not DOM elements, so they cannot be styled with CSS, unfortunately.

See the [Cesium Picking Demo](https://sandcastle.cesium.com/?src=Picking.html) and click the "Pick Entity" button at the top for an example of mouse hover changes to an entity's size and color.

Comment: Thank you the example helped me